# How to recreate /etc/cron.daily/apt?

Tags: debian, apt, cron.daily, upgrade

On my Debian 6.0.8 system the `/etc/cron.daily/apt` file is missing. Therefore, unattended upgrades do not work.

How can I recreate/fix `/etc/cron.daily/apt`?

Comment: It will not help with this problem but to prevent future issues may I suggest etckeeper. All you would have to do is use git to revert the change: https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first find which package contains the missing file:

```
$ dpkg --search /etc/cron.daily/apt
apt: /etc/cron.daily/apt
```

which is that case is the package "apt", and then re-install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install apt
```

edit: added the option to force the miss conf

Comment: This won't work as the missing file is in /etc and is considered a config file. As such it won't be installed again when doing --reinstall; unless you se  -o DPkg::options::=--force-confmiss

Comment: Correct, in that case we need to use the `-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss"`, so for that example it's `$ sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" --reinstall install apt`

Comment: This was very helpful as my virtual hosting provider decided it would be a good idea to remove this file, so even though I thought I had enabled automatic security updates, nothing was actually updated.

Comment: Same thing here with OpenVZ `ubuntu-12.04-x86_64.tar.gz` template.

Answer (score 1):

You should extract the apt deb package in a temp location and then copy the missing file to where it should be.
For instance if your apt cache still contains the deb package apt you can do:

```
cd /tmp
dpkg -x /var/cache/apt/archives/apt_0.9.7.9+deb7u1_amd64.deb .
cp /tmp/etc/cron.daily/apt /etc/cron.daily/
```

If you don't have the deb file in your cache anymore, just download it and apply the same procedure.